# Display output Using Arraylist from string in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

In this application I need to display check or uncheck name from. I am able to do that successfully. But my output has starting and closing square bracket and commas with every output as shown in figure. I want it to be only name without any square brackets**[]** and commas**,** 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDpIs.png)

```
package com.example.jaspreetsingh.selectlist;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.name;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Names> nameList;
    NameAdapter nameAdapter;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    boolean selection;
    ArrayList<String> summary = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        displayViewList();
    }

    public void displayViewList() {

        nameList = new ArrayList<Names>();
        nameList.add(new Names("Mike", "Warner", false));
        nameList.add(new Names("Chris", "Evans", false));
        nameList.add(new Names("Robert", "Dowery", false));
        nameList.add(new Names("Jon", "Jones", false));
        nameList.add(new Names("Tom", "Brady", false));

        nameAdapter = new NameAdapter(nameList, this);

        listView.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int pos = listView.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Names n = nameList.get(pos);
            n.setSelected(isChecked);

            selection = isChecked;
            firstName = n.getFirstName();
            lastName = n.getLastName();
            String fullName = firstName + lastName;

            if (selection) {
                summary.add(firstName);
            }
            if (!selection) {
                summary.remove(firstName);
            }
        }
    }


    public void button(View view) {
        displayText(summary);
    }

    public void displayText(ArrayList<String> result) {
        TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text_view);
        resultTextView.setText(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below methods

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list)
     {
         return TextUtils.join(",", list);
     }

     public static List<String> stringToList(String string)
     {
        if(string==null)
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        else
            return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(string, ",")));
     }
```